# Regular expression, read from start of string

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help with a regular expression I'm trying to develop in relation to retrieving Jira check-in ID's from a message. I need to be able to given this string:

```
WYP-857, GL-1723 and then some message GTY-817 about the check-in.
```

Match the values `WYP-857` and `GL-1723`. The criteria is that I must match two to five alpha characters, followed by a hyphen and then three or more numbers. These individual matches must start at the beginning of the string and can have multiple occurrences separated by commas, semi-colons or spaces. In this case `GTY-817` should not be matched because it is not at the start of the string. All attempts I have made thus far have just seemed to match `WYP-857, GL-1723` entirely and not returned individual matches. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So if you have complete match of those starting jira IDs you can then process this string again, getting individual IDs. Two-step processing. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah I could potentially do that although I would like to do it in one step if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}-\d{3,}([,;\s][a-zA-Z]{2,5}-\d{3,})*
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy:

```
(^|,\ )[A-Z]{2,5}-\d{3}
```

http://tinyurl.com/clt367h

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,5}-[0-9]{3}[0-9]*(, [a-zA-Z]{2,5}-[0-9]{3}[0-9]*)+
```

This should return the initial `WYP-857, GL-1723`, which you can then separate using another `Regex` match (`[a-zA-Z]{2,5}-[0-9]{2}[0-9]*`) or using `Split`.

Admittedly, using this method you will still need to perform *two* operations to actually get a list of separate IDs.